# Determine the resulting Boolean matrix of

Tags: linear-algebra, boolean-algebra

Determine the resulting Boolean matrix of

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tTjv.png)

I have a doubt when I'm going to multiply the resultant with the 2x2 matrix, it turns out that the resultant is 3x3, you can multiply matrices of different dimesion, can you explain me,

I made this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCgbd.jpg)

The picture in Spanish says in order:

Disjunction   | Conjunction

Determine the resulting Boolean matrix.

This is supposed to multiply, but I see that they are matrices with different dimensions. As I do?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Be aware that your title is non-descriptive. To get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are. It is discouraged to rely on external links. Proper formatting is expected; for some information about writing math at this site see e.g.
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are you sure it's not a [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_linear_maps)?

Comment: @Fabio Somenzi This "circled point" operator is almost surely, as you say, a tensor product giving a $6 \times 4$ matrix, maybe known by o852734  under the term "Kronecker product" (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerProduct.html)

Comment: Given the first image, I would think that the OP needs to calculate the Boolean Product as opposed to the Tensor Product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the first link, it seems that you need to calculate the Boolean Product. Calculating this is the same as calculating a regular product of two matrices except that the +'s denote disjunction (OR) and the $\cdot$'s denote conjunction (AND) like they normally do in Boolean algebra. Since you have the product of a $3 \times 2$ and a $2 \times 2$ matrix, the resulting matrix will be $3 \times 2$.

If $A$ is the first matrix, $B$ is the second, and $C$ is the Boolean Product of the two, then the element in row $i$ column $j$ of $C$ will be the Boolean dot product of row $i$ in $A$ with column $j$ in $B$.